# Building/deploying a simple Word addin

Tags: .net-4.0, vsto

I am trying to build a simple addin for Word 2007 using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0. It's a relatively simple addin, which brings up a save dialog and saves the document as a Word 2003 document.

The addin runs fine in Word under Debug mode, but does not run under Release or when I create a setup project for it. (It does create the registry keys under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\Word\Addins and they look to be correct) I don't get any errors, and the addin isn't listed under the Disabled Addins either.

I tried adding the Addin manually but it says that it isn't a valid addin.  The version of Office is 32-bit, running under Windows 7 64-bit.

Or are there even any alternatives to using VSTO (VBA?) that will let me add a tab to the Ribbon?

Comment: To see what is going on follow the procedure at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms269003(v=vs.80).aspx (specifally the last paragraph about VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS

Answer (score 0):

You can use IRibbonExtensibility interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonextensibility.aspx) to avoid using VSTO.